# Cannot link to python and opencv libraries in Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, linker, g++, anaconda

This is probably more of a g++ problem than anything else, but I'm trying to link against libraries that are installed in Anaconda, but cannot seem to find them. I have the following compilation command:

```
 g++  -O3 -shared -Wl,-no-undefined -o _MakeDataPyExt.so src/pyext.o -L/data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib -L/data2/software/stable/CUDA/5.5.22/lib64 -lpthread
```

The output of this compilation has many complaints like the following:

```
pyext.cpp:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
pyext.cpp:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
```

I can see that /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib has python and opencv libs

```
 $ ls /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

returns

```
 /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

Similarly,

```
 $ ls /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libopencv*
```

returns several libs, among which(I believe) the important ones are:

```
 /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libopencv_core.so 
 /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4
 /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.6
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have the header files, such as `Python.h` installed? You'll also need to OpenCV development files as well.

Comment: @MattDMo - Yes, I do. I used them to create src/pyext.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see that /data1/software/analysis/anaconda/lib has python and opencv libs

That's good, but it's not sufficient: you actually need to *list* the libraries you want on the link line:

```
g++ ... -L... -lpython2.7 -lopencv_core -lpthread
```

Did you expect the linker to magically add them to your link line just because you add `-L` pointing to the directory where these libraries are? No linker that I know of does that.